# How to remove null and replace with a string value in ansible

Tags: ansible, json-query

How to remove `null` and replace with a string `novlaue`?

I have below output stored in variable `out1`

```json
{
    "out1": [
        [
            {
                "destination": "dest-a",
                "interface": "e1/1",
                "metric": "10",
                "name": "A"
            },
            {
                "destination": "dest-b",
                "interface": "e1/2",
                "metric": "10",
                "name": "B"
            },
            {
                "destination": "dest-c",
                "interface": null,
                "metric": "10",
                "name": "C"
            },
            {
                "destination": "dest-d",
                "interface": null,
                "metric": "10",
                "name": "B"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I have a `json_query` in my code:

```yaml
- debug: msg="{{out1 |json_query(myquery)}}"
  vars:
     myquery: "[].{dest: destination ,int: interface}"        
  register: out2
```

Above code will print the following:

```json
{
    "msg": [
        {
            "dest": "dest-a",
            "int": "e1/1"
        },
        {
            "dest": "dest-b",
            "int": "e/12"
        },
        {
            "dest": "dest-c",
            "int": null
        },
        {
            "dest": "dest-d",
            "int": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to replace or remove `null` with the string `novalue`.

I looked into some posts and found `default("novalue")` can do the trick but in my case it is not working. I tried following added `default("novalue")` to my `debug` task, but I am getting an error.
I am sure that the error resides in `myquery`, the way I interpret/understand `default()` might be wrong and might be used wrongly.

Can anyone help me here please?

```yaml
- debug: msg="{{out1 |json_query(myquery)}}"
  vars:
     myquery: "[].{dest: destination ,int: interface|default("novalue")}"        
  register: out2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Otherwise, with another JMESPath expression to achieve this, you can use an [or expression `||`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html), that will display the value of `interface` or a string that you are free to define.

So, given your JSON:

```json
[
    {
        "destination": "dest-a",
        "interface": "e1/1",
        "metric": "10",
        "name": "A"
    },
    {
        "destination": "dest-b",
        "interface": "e1/2",
        "metric": "10",
        "name": "B"
    },
    {
        "destination": "dest-c",
        "interface": null,
        "metric": "10",
        "name": "C"
    },
    {
        "destination": "dest-d",
        "interface": null,
        "metric": "10",
        "name": "B"
    }
]
```

And the JMESPath query

```
[].{dest: destination ,int: interface || 'novalue'}
```

This yields

```json
[
  {
    "dest": "dest-a",
    "int": "e1/1"
  },
  {
    "dest": "dest-b",
    "int": "e1/2"
  },
  {
    "dest": "dest-c",
    "int": "novalue"
  },
  {
    "dest": "dest-d",
    "int": "novalue"
  }
]
```

And your task ends up being:

```yaml
- debug: 
    msg: "{{ out1 | json_query(_query) }}"
  vars:
     _query: "[].{dest: destination ,int: interface || 'novalue')}"        
  register: out2
```

Comment: worked, thank you very much

Comment: Note that this will replace any non null but `false` values with your string as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the jinja2 `default` filter inside a jmespath (i.e. json_query) expression. This can't work.

You can use the jmespath function [`not_null`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#not-null) in this case

The playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    "out1": [
      [
        {
          "destination": "dest-a",
          "interface": "e1/1",
          "metric": "10",
          "name": "A"
        },
        {
          "destination": "dest-b",
          "interface": "e1/2",
          "metric": "10",
          "name": "B"
        },
        {
          "destination": "dest-c",
          "interface": null,
          "metric": "10",
          "name": "C",
        },
        {
          "destination": "dest-d",
          "interface": null,
          "metric": "10",
          "name": "B"
        }
      ]
    ]

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ out1 | json_query(myquery) }}"
      vars:
        myquery: >-
          [].{dest: destination ,int: not_null(interface, 'no value')}
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "dest": "dest-a",
            "int": "e1/1"
        },
        {
            "dest": "dest-b",
            "int": "e1/2"
        },
        {
            "dest": "dest-c",
            "int": "no value"
        },
        {
            "dest": "dest-d",
            "int": "no value"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"**How to remove 'null' and replace it with a string 'no value'?**"*

---

**update**

A: Use Jinja

```yaml
    out2: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in out1 %}
      - {% for j in i %}
      - {% if j.interface == None -%}
        {{ j|combine({'interface': 'no value'}) }}
        {% else -%}
        {{ j }}
        {% endif -%}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  out2:
    - - {destination: dest-a, interface: e1/1, metric: '10', name: A}
      - {destination: dest-b, interface: e1/2, metric: '10', name: B}
      - {destination: dest-c, interface: no value, metric: '10', name: C}
      - {destination: dest-d, interface: no value, metric: '10', name: B}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    out1:
      - - {destination: dest-a, interface: e1/1, metric: '10', name: A}
        - {destination: dest-b, interface: e1/2, metric: '10', name: B}
        - {destination: dest-c, interface: null, metric: '10', name: C}
        - {destination: dest-d, interface: null, metric: '10', name: B}

    out2: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in out1 %}
      - {% for j in i %}
      - {% if j.interface == None -%}
        {{ j|combine({'interface': 'no value'}) }}
        {% else -%}
        {{ j }}
        {% endif -%}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: out2|to_yaml
```

---

**origin**

A: The variable *out1* is a list of lists. Let's iterate it and create *out2* with *null* replaced by *'no value'* string. In each loop create the list of *interface* attributes with *null* replaced. Combine this list with the item and add it to the new list. The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        out2: "{{ out2|d([]) + [item|zip(_item)|map('combine')] }}"
      loop: "{{ out1 }}"
      vars:
        _item: "{{ item|json_query(_query) }}"
        _query: |
          [].{interface: not_null(interface, 'no value')}
```